# Report Viewer Assembly cant be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

So basically im trying to get a report viewer in my project, i've referenced the `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` and ive also added the register:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

to my asp.

when i run this i get the error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

and is highlighting the register as the problem with the code.. any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: Have you installed the Microsoft Report Viewer runtime? http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35747 It could be a missing dependency as the error says.

Comment: done, still not working, now i just get this error: _The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file_  but when i try that it gives me an error 502

Comment: Which 502 error you have got? Have you sure there was correct `ReportViewer` assembly version installed in GAC?

Comment: it is 100% the right version and it may be 500 actually.. Internal server error